# One-to-rest Weight vectors in one-to-one multiclass SVC

Tags: svm, libsvm, multi-class

I'm attempting to generate some one-to-rest weight vectors for a multi-class SVC for feature selection purposes. However, I'm current using one of the several LibSVM ports, which inherently performs one-to-one in multi-class classifications.

The columns of the sv_conf output does not appear to me to be duals of one-to-rest classifications. But is there a way to re-construct one-to-rest feature weights from the output of one-to-one classifications, or I'd have to run several one-to-one and obtain the weight vectors separately for each class?

Comment: Too much specific jargon is being used. The question is so focused it has more to do with interpreting a specific program than interpreting statistics, methods or anything relating to this site. If the question can be made into one that asks something about interpretation of a statistical method as opposed to a specific computer software, that should be done.

Comment: I have re-focused the question; please review if it's still off-topic.

Comment: Better, and since you seem to have someone answering you, I have suggested reopening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do one-to-one classification mode, there *is no* single weight vector; there are $\binom{m}{2}$ if you have $m$ classes. You can reconstruct each of those vectors from the appropriate entries of `sv_coef`, though.

Comment: What I'm not so sure about extracting these `sv_coef` entries is, because every one-to-one classifier has two SVs, do I need to extract the `sv_coef` entries for both SVs, and if so, how do I combine the results? I saw at least one literature (`e1071`'s internals) that would sum both `SVs' * sv_coef` from the same classifier, but I haven't seen this elsewhere.